# Preg Match Subpaterns - How to match all TDs following after a string

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$str = '<tr>
<td>First thing</td>
<td>some stuff <b>150</b></td>
<td>350</td>
<td>250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Second thing</td>
<td>150</td>
<td>350</td>
<td>250</td>
</tr>';
```

**Ideal output:**

Find beginning of word "First" and then get each string inside following TD's, ending by TR and not going further to second row.

**Approach:**

I know I could use several nested preg_match_callback()

Or I could use HTML DOM thing

But for the sake of code, I want to see if it's possible in regex using subpatterns.

```
// This is what I have so far...

preg_match_all('~
<td>
(
    (?:
        (?!</td).  # absolutely no idea what this does
    )*
)
</td>
~isx', $str, $m);


print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so I solved it like this:

```
$pos = stripos($str, "First");
$html_TR = substr($str, $pos, stripos($str, '</tr>', $pos));

$pattern = '~ <td> (?: (?!(<td>|</td>)). | (?R) )*+ </td> ~x';

preg_match_all($pattern, $html_TR, $matches);
$html_TDs = $matches[0];

print_r($html_TDs);
```

Not the power ultimate solution, but it'll do :(

I guess I would have to use 2 recursive subpatterns to match the TR, I wasn't able to do it.